# Why are some of my cron jobs not sending emails?

Tags: crontab, mailto

To send emails, I use the standard configuration with:

```
MAILTO="example@gmail.com"
```

Here is the content of my crontab:

```
00 3 * * 2 echo "Internal Backup (mysql) has started!" && tar -zvcf /home/backups/sql/01_MondaySQL.tgz /home/mysql/automysqlbackup
00 4 * * 2 echo "Internal Backup (www/dev) has started!" && tar -zvcf /home/backups/www/daily/01_Monday_www_dev.tgz /home/www/dev
```

The first job works perfectly. When it finish, I receive an email with this as subject:

"echo "Internal Backup (mysql) has started!" && tar -zvcf /home/backups/sql/01_MondaySQL.tgz /home/mysql/automysqlbackup"

And the email contains a list of all files archived during the job.

I would like exactly same for the second line. Despite this second job is well done (archive 01_MondaySQL.tgz created), I don't receive an email as for job.

I am facing the same issue with some rsync jobs. For example this job works perfectly:

```
00 16 * * * echo "Mobile Backup has started!" && rsync --delete -aPvz -e "ssh -i /root/.sshkeys/diskstation-rsync-key" /home/backups/mobile/ root@www.example.com:/volume1/Backups/mobile/
```

But this one has same problem (no emails sent):

```
00 14 * * * echo "Desktop Backup has started!" && rsync --delete -aPvz -e "ssh -i /root/.sshkeys/diskstation-rsync-key" /home/backups/desktop/ root@www.example.com:/volume1/Backups/desktop/
```

I checked logs but nothing seems suspicious.

Comment: did you check the mail logs at those times to see if the email was sent?  I would also try to isolate this by removing the MAILTO line so emails are delivered to the cron user.  You can verify local mails with the 'mail' command.

Comment: Emails are not sent, they don't appear in mail log. I am trying without MAILTO line

Comment: I removed MAILTO line, but nothing has changed.

Comment: you then have an issue with output not being picked up by stdout in your cron job.  My prefefence for this type of job that needs email confirmation is to put it in shell script and at then end just send an email from within the script.  See an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you appear to have an issue with stdout since thats where cron decides to send email to not.  If there is no output then cron send no email.

My preference would be to put all in a script like this:

```
echo "Mobile Backup has started!"
tar -zvcf /home/backups/sql/01_MondaySQL.tgz /home/mysql/automysqlbackup  > /home/report.txt
mail -s 'backup Report' example@gmail.com < /home/report.txt
```

and your cron would simply call that script.